# SEO friendly links with htaccess - redirecting dynamic links to static

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a website in which i would like to switch into SEO friendly links. To spare some work I would like to make the redirections via htaccess, so that the old dynamic links like:

```
mydomain.com/mypage.php?id=1&something=2
```

will be redirected to more friendly one:

```
mydomain.com/mypage/1/2/
```

As far as I understand I need those redirects so that the search engines won't punish me for the duplicated content and since I need to do them i thought it might be easier to just made them instead of changing the links on every pages to the friendly one - I am using normal html form for that so it wouldn't be very straight forward.
I am trying to do that with the code in htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /directory for mydomain.com/

RewriteRule ^mypage\.php?id=([0-9]+)&something=([0-9]+)$ ^mypage/$1/$2 [R=302,QSA]
RewriteRule ^mypage/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ ^mypage.php?id=$1&something=$2  [QSA]
```

But it's not working. I think one problem could be with "?" in:

```
^mypage.php?id=([0-9]+)....
```

I might be wrong, but through many test I concluded that I cannot use the ? mark there but not sure how to slove it.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot match query string in `RewriteRule`. Correct way to handle this is using these rules in the `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test_redirects/

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/test_redirects/([^.]+)\.php\?id=([^\s&]+)&something=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/%3? [R=302,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2&something=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for quick answer. I tried your code and it rewrite the url to seo friendly but the page didn't open - error 404 requested page not found on the server. Does it mean that i didn't read the second rule?

Comment: What is the page URL you see in browser when you get 404?

Comment: The rewrited one. In the example it would be: mydomain.com/mypage/1/2 but I was using an url to point into the old one: mydomain.com/mypage.php?id=1&something=2

Comment: I tested again and these rules are working fine. To test comment out 2 lines below `# external redirect` line and then enter `mydomain.com/mypage/1/2` in browser.

Comment: I have checked it and I think I now what's the problem. The folder in which the page is stored is written twice after the redirection. Probabl its my fault as I written that I want to use it in mydomain.com but for tests I have a folder like this mydomain.com/test_redirects/ where the files and htaccess is stored. So now after redirection we have:  mydomain.com/test_redirects/test_redirects/1/2        Sorry for confusion, but can you please tell me how what to change so that the formula will work also in subfolder